# Does the SAS (stability augmentation system) actuators of f-14 use jet-pipe or flapper-nozzle technology?

Tags: flight-controls, control-surfaces

F-14 uses electrohydraulic servo actuators for its SAS. What type of hydraulic amplification is used in F-14? jet-pipe, flapper-nozzle or something else?